Why does my winston.js formatter execute on messages that'll never be printed?
Why I'm asking: I want my winston log messages to show what file and line number they come from.
According to my research, I need to create a logform formatter to do this. Here's what I came up with. It works:
import { parse } from 'stacktrace-parser';
import { format } from 'winston';
import { basename } from 'node:path'; 

export const logPrefix = format((info, opts) => {
  console.log(`here!!`);
  const stack = new Error().stack;
  const stackFrames = parse(stack); // *
  const logFrameIndex =
    stackFrames.findIndex((stackFrame) => {
      return stackFrame.file.endsWith(`create-logger.js`);
    }) + 1;

  if (logFrameIndex === 0) {
    info.message = `unknown: ${info.message}`;
  } else {
    const logFrame = stackFrames[logFrameIndex];
    let prefix = new Date().toISOString();
    prefix += ' ' + basename(logFrame.file);
    prefix += `#${logFrame.lineNumber}`;
    info.message = `${prefix}: ${info.message}`;
  }

  return info;
});

I decided to run a performance test on my project because it wasn't as performant as I had hoped, and the profiler told me that the line that calls parse() is the slowest part of my code.
By adding a simple console.log to my code, I learned that the logPrefix is executed whenever a message is logged, even if the message will never print. i.e., on a log.debug(...) when the log level is warn or error.
It seems strange to me that winston formats messages it will never log; is my code causing this? Is the way I use logPrefix causing this?
import { createLogger, Logger, format, transports } from 'winston';
import { logPrefix } from './log-prefix';

export type Category =
  | 'DEFAULT'
  | 'another category'
  | 'even another category';

const logLevels = ['error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug'] as const;
export type LogLevel = (typeof logLevels)[number];

const loggerPool = new Map<LogLevel, Logger>([
  ['debug', createLogger(buildLoggerOptions('debug'))],
  ['info', createLogger(buildLoggerOptions('info'))],
  ['warn', createLogger(buildLoggerOptions('warn'))],
  ['error', createLogger(buildLoggerOptions('error'))],
]);

function buildLoggerOptions(configuredLevel: LogLevel) {
  return {
    level: configuredLevel,
    format: format.combine(logPrefix(), format.simple()),
    transports: new transports.Console(),
    exceptionHandlers: new transports.Console(),
    rejectionHandlers: new transports.Console(),
    exitOnError: false,
  };
}

export const getLogger = (categoryName: Category = 'DEFAULT'): Logger => {
  if (getEnvLevelValue('DEFAULT') === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      `Logger Configuration Error: Environment Variable '${getEnvLevelKey(
        'DEFAULT'
      )}' does not exist.`
    );
  }

  const configuredLevel = getEnvLevelValue(categoryName);
  if (configuredLevel === undefined) {
    getLogger('DEFAULT').warn(
      `Environment Variable '${getEnvLevelKey(
        categoryName
      )}' does not exist. Defaulting to 'debug'.`
    );
  }

  return loggerPool.get(configuredLevel ?? 'debug');
};

const getEnvLevelKey = (categoryName: Category): string => {
  return `logger.${categoryName}.level`;
};

const getEnvLevelValue = (categoryName: Category): LogLevel | undefined => {
  const value = process.env[getEnvLevelKey(categoryName)];

  if (value === undefined) {
    return undefined;
  } else if (includes(logLevels, value)) {
    return value;
  }
  throw new Error(
    `Invalid value for getEnvLevelKey(categoryName): '${getEnvLevelKey(
      categoryName
    )}' Expected one of ${logLevels}`
  );
};

function includes<S extends string>(
  haystack: readonly S[],
  needle: string
): needle is S {
  const _haystack: readonly string[] = haystack;
  return _haystack.includes(needle);
}

I'm using winston 3.13.0 (the latest at this time).

I found an issue in the winstonjs repo that appears to be the same, but I'm not sure if this issue will turn out to be a bug, working as designed, a feature request, or if the problem lies in my code.
